# Durable subscriber with JMS Connector Alpakka

Tags: jms, akka, alpakka

Using Alpakka, we can create a non-durable subscriber for any topic using the below code:

```
Source<String, NotUsed> jmsTopicSource = JmsSource
    .textSource(JmsSourceSettings
        .create(connectionFactory)
        .withTopic("topic")
        .withBufferSize(10)
    );
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make this topic subscriber durable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the creation of durable consumers is supported in Alpakka's JMS connector, as of version 0.9. In the internal API, [`JmsConnector`](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v0.9/jms/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/jms/JmsConnector.scala#L91) is calling [`Session#createConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createConsumer-javax.jms.Destination-):

```
private[jms] def createConsumer()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[jms.MessageConsumer] =
  Future {
    session.createConsumer(destination)
  }
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to invoke any of the methods (e.g., [`Session#createDurableConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createDurableConsumer-javax.jms.Topic-java.lang.String-)) that the JMS `Session` object provides to create durable consumers.

Comment: ok .that's helpful but is it possible to extend an alpakka API or change its configuration to make it durable ?

Comment: can we extend the GraphStage< SourceShape< Message > > and then override the method which creates an consumer ??  @chunjef